# How to hook into the windows Explorer (for network based file stores, e.g. dropbox)

Tags: windows, dropbox, google-cloud-storage

I might get in trouble for this question. I am willing to re-write it.

I am assuming that most major online storage services such as DropBox, OneDrive, Box, GoogleDrive etc. expose their service to the web via WebDAV. Ok, now my question is for windows client.

How does the client application hook into the windows os, so that it file requests for a file at path: F:\myfolder, etc. map to WebDav service.

I am looking for an overview of the process for how they:

1. Discover cached files are stale
2. Discover new folder structures on the server
3. Map their folders to the NTFS structure, so that standard windows file i/o finds the files
4. Is there some sort of open source toolware that could be used to connect to a generic webdav service so that we could build our own custom client manager?

In our case, we have files with a geospatial component. So we don't to browse the server by folder structure, but rather with a map interface, and have that as the filter for what gets replicated to the client folder structure. So we are looking for components to re-use.

Comment: Your first assumption is mostly wrong. DropBox does not provide WebDAV, nor do I believe the others do. DropBox keeps the files local, and thats what you access. No hooking.

Comment: Perhaps an idle curiousity question. There is something called DropDav that exposes DropBox as WebDAV. Do you have any idea why the drobbox folks don't use WebDAV? Is there a known performance issue? security?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a [Windows Shell Namspace Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095(v=vs.85).aspx).  This will give you access to a data folder hierarchy in Explorer that is not based on traditional files. The disadvantage is you will not be able to access the storage on the command-line, only in Explorer.

Comment: OK, but on my windows10 box, it seems the connection is deeper than the Explorer app. I.e. Even in crufty old programs such as quicken I can do a file open dialog, and I see both dropbox and onedrive. I am no concerned with the command-line. But I do want to hook at the level of the File API to do open, read, etc

Comment: The Namespace Extension is also visible in e.g. the File Open Dialog, which embeds an Explorer view after all.